# Generating Pivot Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a `SQL Server` query that generates the following result:

```
| Department | Round Type  | Total | Passed |
|:-----------|------------:|:------|--------|
|     MD     |   Spring    |  10   |   8    |
|     MD     |   Winter    |  15   |   10   |
```

How to pivot the above result set on Total and Passed columns for Department `MD` in `SQL Server`???

**Desired Result**

```
| Department | Spring Total | Spring Passed | Winter Total | Winter Passed |
|:-----------|:-------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|
|     MD     |      10      |        8      |      15      |       10
```

Comment: Please update your question to show the desired result

Comment: Are the values in the column `Round Type` _fixed_ - as in they can _only_ be `Spring` or `Winter`?

Comment: They can be these four values `Spring`, `Summar`, `fall`, `Winter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a solution that *doesn't* use the `PIVOT` command, but achieves the same result.

```
--demo setup
Declare @Table1 table
    (Department varchar(12), [Round Type] varchar(13), Total int, Passed int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Department, [Round Type], Total, Passed)
VALUES
    ('MD', 'Spring', '10', '8'),
    ('MD', 'Winter', '15', '10')
;

--Solution
SELECT department
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Spring'
                THEN Total
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Spring Total]
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Spring'
                THEN Passed
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Spring Passed]
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Summer'
                THEN Total
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Summer Total]
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Summer'
                THEN Passed
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Summer Passed]
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Fall'
                THEN Total
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Fall Total]
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Fall'
                THEN Passed
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Fall Passed]
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Winter'
                THEN Total
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Winter Total]
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN [Round Type] = 'Winter'
                THEN Passed
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [Winter Passed]
FROM @Table1
GROUP BY Department
```

---

```
| department | Spring Total | Spring Passed | Summer Total | Summer Passed | Fall Total | Fall Passed | Winter Total | Winter Passed |
|------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
| MD         | 10           | 8             | 0            | 0             | 0          | 0           | 15           | 10            |
```